# Android app not showing in "All Apps"

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

After some changes I made to my app that I made so it would show the activities in a different order, the app icon no longer appears in the "All Apps" screen on the android device. It does, however, show up on the "Recent" screen. I think it has something to do with a configuration error in my manifest file. I would like the ServerChoiceActivity to be the one represented by the icon, and it's what launches when launch it from the recent screen, but the fact that there is no icon on the "All apps" or "Downloaded" pages confuses me quite a bit.

The application section of my manifest file:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".ServerChoiceActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ServerSettingsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/settings_title">
        <intent-filter>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ImageShareActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".MultiImageUploadActivity"
        android:taskAffinity="test.affinity"
        android:label="@string/multiupload_title">
        <intent-filter>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:taskAffinity="test.affinity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:label="Bucket"
        android:name=".BucketActivity">
        <intent-filter>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any suggestions? The app works as expected when I launch it, and it was working fine, including showing the icon before I modified the manifest file.

Comment: Try adding in the modifications to the original one-by-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly because you have this in your `ServerChoiceActivity` intent-filter:

```
<data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
```